# Количество элементов не до конца заполненного массива

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, char

*Есть программа, в процессе её выполнения пользователь выбирает один или более элементов, элементы записываются в массив константного размера. Т.е. если пользователь выберет один элемент - в массиве будет занята всего одна ячейка.*
Существуют ли способы узнать **реальное количество элементов в массиве** стандартной функцией языка. Стандартный способ `sizeof(variable)/sizeof(variable[0])` тут не сработает, массив должен иметь тип `conct char` либо `char*`. Про возможность использовать `vector`/`string` и цикл пробежки по элементам осведомлен.

---

Такого функционала НЕТ! Необходимо использовать `vektor`, `string`, цикл пробежки по элементам или дополнительную отслеживающую переменную.

Comment: Если имеется массив определенного размера - все его элементы **реальны**, независимо от того, сколько ячеек записаны пользователем (так что и способ с `size`/`sizeof` тут не работают, возвращая количество элементов массива, а не количество записанных элементов). Вижу выход только в добавлении отслеживающей это количество переменной (раз уж вектора не используем).

Comment: У меня такие же соображения

Comment: Массив не может иметь тип `const char` или `char *`. Стандартный способ определения количества элементов в массиве это `::std::size(arr)`. Количество "занятых" ячеек вам придется отслеживать самостоятельно или воспользоваться каким-нибудь сторонним контейнером типа `::boost::static_vector`

Comment: Массивы так не работают. Они не сжимаются и не растягиваются. Массив это по сути память, зарезервированная под определенное количество подряд идущих элементов, и их количество там не хранится. Ты можешь не использовать ее всю, но программа не может знать об этом. Нужно хранить количество элементов в отдельной переменной, либо делать как в строках признак конца строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что вы имели в виду тип элементов массива `conct char`, а не тип самого массива. Но в этом случае вы ничего не сможете записать в массив.:)

Если массив не константный, и пользователь заносит произвольное число элементов в массив, то имеется две возможности.

Первая - это отслеживать число записанных элементов в массив в некоторой отдельно выделенной переменной.

Вторая - это включать в массив некоторый символ завершения, которым, например, для символьного массива может быть символом `'\0'`. Но в этом случае массив может содержать только на единицу меньше символов, введенных пользователем, чем выделено в самом массиве.
Определить число актуальных элементов в массиве вы сможете через поиск этого символа завершения, например, используя стандартную функцию `strchr`.

Answer (score -1):

Если ваш массив, это `vector`, то можно получить кол-во таким способом

```
for(int i = a; vector.size(); i++)
{
 stringstream ss;
 ss << i;
 string str = ss.str();
}
```